# How can I print data on more than one excel worksheet in C#

Tags: c#, html, excel, stringbuilder, file-writing

I have a C# application for creating an excel. The code is given below,

```
public void CreateExcelSheet()
    {
        StringBuilder sbWriteBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<html xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<head>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=windows-1252'>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<xml>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");

        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:Panes>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</x:Panes>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");


        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:Name>Sheet2</x:Name>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<x:Panes>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</x:Panes>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");


        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</xml>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<![endif]-->");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</head>");    

        //*************Data shouldbe in worksheet 1
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<body>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<table>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr></tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr style='background-color:brown;border:solid;border-width:1px'>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<th>" + "Details of customers on 11/4/2014" + "</th>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</tr>");

        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Balance</td></tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr><td>1234</td><td>Al Bundy</td><td>45</td></tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr><td>1234</td><td>Chris Mary</td><td>20</td></tr>");

        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr></tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</table>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</body>");
        //*************************************************    

        //*************Data shouldbe in worksheet 2
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<body>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<table>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr></tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr style='background-color:brown;border:solid;border-width:1px'>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<th>" + "Details of customers on 11/3/2014" + "</th>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</tr>");

        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Balance</td></tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr><td>9876</td><td>Homer Simpson</td><td>-129</td></tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr><td>5555</td><td>Peter Griffin</td><td>0</td></tr>");  

        sbWriteBuffer.Append("<tr></tr>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</table>");
        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</body>");
        //***************************************************    

        sbWriteBuffer.Append("</html>");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\excel.xls", sbWriteBuffer.ToString());
    }
```

The problem is that I need to get the data printed on 2 worksheets of an excel file. But now Im getting as its writing on the same worksheet. What modification I need to do in this code inorder to achieve my requirement?
How can I print data on more than one worksheet in C#?

In the same code above how can I specify a set of data to show in a particular worksheet? **How can I relate/connect *worksheet* to *table*** in the above code?

Comment: Why don't you use the Microsoft.Office.Interop package ? or at least structure your data like in this project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20228/Using-C-to-Create-an-Excel-Document so you can handle concepts not strings in buffers

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a component for that ? EPPlus is very easy and powerfull:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/